# How to set C3JS tooltip content

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have a situation similar to the example shown in http://c3js.org/samples/data_json.html My simple intention is to get the name of the row (i.e. 'www.site1.com') into the tooltip header. My problem: I cannot find it in the d-values.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find it in d-values, because it's **not a value** actually - **it's a category**.

Have a look at [Category Axis example](http://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html), maybe it helps you:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9']
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. Yes, it is a category, but I don't want to display the category on the x axis. I only want to have it in the tooltip. And my main problem is to address the data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the d-value to address the right category of my JSON, or rather the array in my JSON. (Seemed more complicated since I load the data after I create the chart.)